# Double integral in Cartesian coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

#### Using double integrals

The volume of solid limited by the cylinder $x^2\ + y^2 = 9$ , and plans $z = 0$ and $z = 3 - x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt{3-x^2}}^{\sqrt{3-x^2}} (z_2 - z_1) dy dx $$

Where $z_2=3-x$ is upper surface and $z_1=0$ is lower surface.

Comment: Thank you! @santosh-linkha

Comment: you are welcome :)